# How to expand program memory on an arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

Sometimes I run out of space of the program size for the embedded C program that I want to put on an arduino. So what chip do I need to expand the program memory of the arduino so that I can use bigger C programs with my arduino?

Comment: Considering that [a fellow by the name of Petri Häkkinen](https://plus.google.com/100797925989882885975) put [an arcade-style game](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12623) on an Atmega328P, maybe you should look at saving space in your code? If that isn't practical, as some of the answers say, you can get a bigger chip with more program memory. The Atmega644, for example, comes in a DIP-chip package, amongst others.

Comment: See also https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=226465.0

Comment: can you please explain a bit more your answer ? 2) The Arduino has SPI, so an SD card can be accessed. Any code on the SD card would need to be loaded into executable memory. This is complicated and not for beginners... You mean that you can change or re-program de instruction memory while the program is running ?
Can the running program call the bootloader and load new instructions on a different addresses ? Won´t this age the program memory ? A different solution may be identify rutines in your program and all the "call´s" stored whith the data on a spi external memory... Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An ATmega2560 is the chip to add for more memory when you run out of program memory on an Uno.  Referring to the [Memory](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory) webpage at arduino.cc, you'll see that it has Flash=256KB, SRAM=8KB, EEPROM=4KB, where the ATmega328 chip on the Uno has Flash=32KB, SRAM=2KB, EEPROM=1KB.

When you run out of program memory on an Uno, you have about three choices that are practical:  make the program smaller; remove the bootloader (to free up one or two KB); use a different board with a more-capable processor.  The CPU on an Uno board doesn't have a way to access program bytes from places other than the on-chip 32KB flash.  The CPU on a Mega2560 board starts out with 8 times as much flash, so it can hold bigger programs than an Uno can.

If you remove the bootloader, you could instead program using a USBASP board, as described in a 
[“Program AVR chip using a USBASP with 10 pin cable”](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Program-AVR-chip-using-a-USBASP-with-10-pin-cable.php) article at learningaboutelectronics.com.

Comment: but if you free up the bootloader then how would i use the arduino IDE to program?

Comment: @qwerty10, see last paragraph of edit.   Arduino IDE supports USBASP ok.

Comment: Wouldnt it work with any programmer that can upload code to ATMEGA? Instead of only a USBASP. As I understand it itns not actually using 10 pins but a subset of those pins.

Comment: @qwerty10,  USPASP is an ISP (in system programming) programmer.  Generally, any ISP programmer  can be used to program a chip (with or without a bootloader on it) as long as MOSI, MISO, SCK, RST, VCC, and GND pins are available on the target chip.

Comment: Current Unos use the very compact optiboot bootloader. Removing it will only free 512 bytes.

Comment: @qwerty10: There are versions of the USBASP with a 6 pin connector. The 10 pin connector has 4 redundant pins.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet . I have another question Edgar. If I take out the atmega 328 chip from its socket on the Uno and replace it with using atmega8-16PU instead and I burn this 512 bytes bootloader-does that mean I can use the arduino Uno with the atmega8 like the atmaga328 (but with a subset of the features of the 328). The atmega8 is of course an older chip than the 328 but it still has same pinouts.

Comment: @qwerty10: I am quite confident it should work on the physical level. On the software level however, you will have to convince the Arduino IDE to play well with it. You may try to tell the IDE your board is actually an “Arduino NG or older w/ ATmega8”.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet. So using it as an Arduino NG with atmeg8 chip does this mean that the bootloader will set the fuses on the arduino's atmega8 to use the crystal on the arduino pcb? Or does the bootloader set the fuses on the arduino's atmega8 to use its internal oscillator? This clock info needs to be known to move  from arduino prototype to a permanent PCB version of circuit. How  much memory is left after writing bootlader to atmega8 -is it 7.5 KB instead of 8KB?

Comment: @qwerty10: Your are drifting very far from your original question. That should really be a new question.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet. I would guess, the answer as, because it pin for pin subset of the  atmega328 (i.e. the pins of the 328 can be the same as the mega8) of the uno board hence it  would require a crystal and capacitors.

Answer (score 7):

Another way (other than MCU with more memory) is not using Arduino framework and its libraries. Such level of abstraction is expensive in both ways - memory usage and speed. But that's much harder way. If you need some library, you have to port it (if you haven't found native one) or at least provide required functions from Arduino.

For example in Arduino IDE 1.6.11 empty sketch is using up 444 Bytes of flash. Using one `pinMode` and `digitalWrite(13, ! digitalRead(13));` + `delay(500);` means 964 Bytes. Of course, these are most likely one-timers. If you use six more pins and toggle it, it uses much less program memory than using first one (1192B). But it still grows really fast.

In pure C empty program is about 134 Bytes long. Same functionality (toggling one pin every 500ms) takes 158 Bytes (and it's way faster).

But for hobby project i would go for ATMega2560 or ATMega644/1284 instead.

And you can use direct access to hardware too. Toggle pin sketch with using registers directly and _delay_ms from avr libraries uses 468 Bytes instead of 964B. With delay from Arduino core libraries it's 602B.

Comment: You mean `_delay_ms()`.

Comment: This has the added benefit of actually learning about the mcu that you're using. The AVRs on these Arduinos are much more capable than the "standard library" would have you believe. ++

Answer (score 3):

When asking a broad question, it is helpful to include some details.  Like how much memory you need and why you think you need it.

I once specified a processor at 2 KB program space, 64 bytes RAM and 1 KIPS.
The engineer asked, "MIPS?", and I explained thousands per second.  He replied, "They don't come that slow".  At the end of the project, a huge UI was added and memory got tight... but it still fit with no problem.

So, consider being more thoughtful about the resources being used.

To answer the question:

1. The Arduino does not provide a convenient bus to fetch memory over.
   So, there is no way to plug in a chip to get more memory.
2. The Arduino has SPI, so an SD card can be accessed.
   Any code on the SD card would need to be loaded into executable memory.
   This is complicated and not for beginners...
3. As suggested, tighten up you code.  This is probably a good way to learn.
4. Move to a larger Arduino.

There are different Arduino processors.  Some in the ACR line, others in the ARM line.  Going to a different device in the same family is a relatively modest change and can provide up to 368 Bytes of program FLASH.  But these are not Arduino boards exactly.

The Arduino ARM based devices are very different and use different libraries.

Check out the Arduino Mega 2560 it is very similar to the Uno, has a similar footprint, code should port relatively easily and is inexpensive.

There are also larger devices in the AVR family.

Note, the AVR32 is a different processor and the peripherals are enough different that it is a different device.

If you want to get into very large programs (gigabytes of memory) check out the Beagleboard.  It has a full linux, with virtual memory (see #2 above) and has more powerful I/O mechanisms.

Comment: Perhaps fix some typos, like Wen, 3, and differnt

Comment: I mean, if you fix those typos, someone might vote up your answer...

Answer (score 2):

What about a [raspberry pi zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/zero-grows-camera-connector/)?  I have a couple and use them quite often as arduinos.

Comment: Other architectures should indeed be considered, but an embedded linux system *with mandatory SD card booting* like the pi adds a lot of complexity and is fragile in unique ways, even if not more expensive.  There are a lot of boards based on smaller, more highly intergrated ARM MCUs which are much more similar to an Arduino in terms of applications, while being drastically more capable.  But if you need a lot of processing, or megabytes of memory, then yes, these complexities start to be worthwhile.

Comment: I also prefer the zero because it is so flexible.  You can add more storage or embed it in projects while also having a large enough processor to do pretty much anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look into other platforms. For instance, a Teensy 3.2 is Arduino compatible and has a 2KB eeprom and 64KB of RAM.